# "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"

Tags: support, review, spam

I was reviewing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652959/how-do-i-prove-that-cp-frac-1-2-acbc-ab), and a warning appeared, stating

```
Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully
```

Now the question may be considered off topic, but I cannot see how it could have (automatically) flagged as possible spam, given that there is no link and the text is a question. Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The author of that question is in close proximity (network topology wise) to someone that had been posting spam suggested edits and answers across the network. This is (partly) why we don't automatically purge recent contributions from suspicious origins when they're rejected, there's a *small* chance that someone might get caught in the metaphorical cross fire.

This is precisely why the review system asks you to pay extra close attention, so that (1) people that aren't don't inadvertently rubber stamp something that statistically is *extremely* likely to be spam, and that (2) this rare exceptional case can be caught and everything made right again in the universe.

*Most* times when hosts all over a given network have been spamming multiple sites, *everything* in that neighborhood is probably junk. This might happen one out of 10,000 times (network aggregate), but it can happen, hence the message.